# Question about a remark on quantization of Coulomb branches

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, quantization

I will follow the definition of Coulomb branches of $3d$ $\mathcal{N}=4$ gauge theories from the paper by Braverman, Finkelberg and Nakajima, *Towards a mathematical definition of Coulomb branches of 3-dimensional N=4 gauge theories, II*

Physical considerations aside, the above paper gives us a recipe that, given a complex reductive group $G$ and a representation of contangent type $M = N \oplus N^*$, where $N$ is a finite dimensional representation of $G$, produces a normal Poisson variety $\mathcal{M}_C(G,N)$, which is symplectic on its smooth locus. The way the variety is constructued, the algebra of regular functions on the Coulomb branch has a natural quantization denoted by $\mathcal{A}_h(G,N)$, which is a finitely generated left and right Noetherian domain, and hence admits a skew field of fractions, denoted by $\operatorname{Frac}$.

In the above paper, Remark 5.23, it is explained that $\operatorname{Frac}\mathcal{A}_h(G,N)$ is the same as the division ring of fractions of the $W$-invariants of the algebra of $h$-difference operators on $\mathfrak{t}$, where $\mathfrak{t}$ is the Lie algebra of a maximal torus $T$ of $G$ and $W$ is its Weyl group.

I'm having some problem in figuring out what exactly this Remark says. I've seen different algebras given the name of *algebra of difference operators on an affine space*. So I would like to know exactly what algebra we are talking about in this case. Having setled this first question, I would like to know exactly how $W$ acts by algebra automorphisms on this algebra.

This topic is somewhat distant from my usual research, so I am aware that the answers to my questions are problably obvious for the specialists. Hence, I apologize in advance if my questions are too trivial.

---

**Important Edit** It seems that the previous question boils down to the following. Choose a maximal torus $T \subset G$, with associated Weyl group $W$. Let $N_T$ be the restriction of the $G$ representation $N$ to a $T$ representation.

What algebra is $\mathcal{A}_h(T,N_T)$, and how the Weyl group $W$ acts on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algebra of difference operators is very explicitly described at the beggining of the appendix (section A(i)) of [Coulomb branches of 3d N=4 quiver gauge theories and slices in the affine Grassmannian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03625.pdf).  It is an algebra with generated by polynomial functions on $ \mathbf t$, and translations by elements of the root lattice.

The action of $ W $ comes from its natural action on $ \mathbf t $.

Comment: Thank you very much Joel